# Problem with test automation django app with Jenkins

Tags: django, docker, jenkins, testing

so generally I'm trying to automate some simple tests in my django app with Jenkins. The structure looks like this [structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yoqF8.png).

I tried many different setups like: installing pacakges right into cointiner and trying to test, creating virtualenv inside of it or creating venv outside and importing it from my source version control and running in jenkins but nothing worked. Always i got message that it can't find django module like it could't find enviroment:
Log examples from one of the builds [logfiles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRv4S.png)[logfiles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7Hlm.png)[logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffNus.png)[logfiles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G4U9t.png)

My pipeline looked like this:
[pipeline steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNCNS.png).

Comment: I suggest that you replace the links to screenshots with listing and text... Otherwise the question will be voted down!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the following structure not only for jenkins:

```
.
├── mysite
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── manage.py
│   ├── myapp
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── admin.py
│   │   ├── apps.py
│   │   ├── models.py
│   │   ├── serializers.py
│   │   ├── views.py
│   │   └── urls.py
│   └── mysite
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── asgi.py
│       ├── settings.py
│       ├── urls.py
│       └── wsgi.py
├── tests
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── conftest.py
│   └── test_views.py
├── .dockerignore
├── .gitignore
├── .gitlab-ci.yml
├── .pre-commit-config.yaml
├── docker-compose.yml
├── Dockerfile
├── LICENSE
├── pyproject.toml
├── pytest.ini
├── requirements.txt
├── requirements_testing.txt
├── setup.cfg
├── tox.ini
└── venv # the virtual environment
```

This structure keeps the project files and the test files separate, and it should work for jenkins and also for other CI/CD pipelines.

I created this boilerplate project, that has some more details.
I created this boilerplate project, it won't work out of the box, because it is missing details in `setup.cfg` for example. But I hope it is a good start:

https://github.com/oussjarrousse/boilerplate-django

Comment: Okey, but I see this approach forces me to use pytest instead of built-in django TestCase which my team uses. But I think it's not a big deal to change our method of testing. I have some different questions. You provide here requirements files for app and testing but also there is venv folder. I don't understand why, because I assume Dockerfile is using them and shouldn't that be enough to setup an enviroment? Docker pulls python image and install dependencies. Could you explain me that?

Comment: The nice thing about pytest is that you can use it to run native python unit tests. Also pytest has a pytest-django plugin that provides many useful tools for testing. I recommend it not only for Django and Django projects running Django Rest Frameworks as well as any other Python project you have in mind. It's much more powerful and easy to use in comparison with TestCase.

Comment: the venv is for local development purposes only. I run `python -m venv venv` to create an isolated development environment for the project, then `source venv/bin/activate` to source it and use it. In that case any python pacakage I install with `pip` is installed in that `venv`. I don't include that folder when building the docker image. I basically only copy the `mysite` folder in the Dockerfile. Alternatively you can add `venv` to the `.dockerignore` and in that case it is not copied over to the docker image you are creating with `docker build`. With that said, you point about venv is right.

Comment: I created this boilerplate project. Take a look at the Dockerfile for example...
Of course it won't work out of the box. because it is missing details in `setup.cfg` for example. But I hope it is a good start.

https://github.com/oussjarrousse/boilerplate-django

Comment: Man , thanks so much for such a clear explanation. For sure there is still a lot of work on my way but your anwser made many things clear. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, I also learned something by answering the question and created a boilerplate that I will use in the future... if you "vote up", it will be a win-win situation ;-) or

Comment: I need at least 15 points reputation for it to count as it showed but I clicked it :D.